# Is there any way to end the WSO2 identity server user session from application(SP) side. Is there any endpoint to do that?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to kill the WSO2 identity server user session from my application(SP) logout button. Is there any endpoint to do that. Is it possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the session management REST API in WSO2 IS.

Refer to:
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/session-mgt-rest-api/

Comment: "https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/api/users/v1/me/sessions"  Is there any issue with above endpoint. Session is not deleted even though 204  response comes.

Comment: Before deleting the sessions, did you check the GET request and whether there are any active sessions? Since DELETE is defined to be idempotent, it returns 204 even the no active sessions to delete. Once you confirm that you have active sessions but it doesn't get deleted properly, check whether is there any carbon error logs in the terminal. To verify that the endpoint works properly, Go to the security section of myaccount `https://localhost:9443/myaccount/security` try out terminate all Active Sessions option with an open network tab in the browser.

Comment: Yes, when i invoke GET request it gives me "{}" empty string.  What could be the reason to get empty sessions. When i go to security tab and terminate all, it terminated all sessions from the UI. Where could be the missing part for me. Here is my endpoint "https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/api/users/v1/me/sessions". Am i missing any configuration in admin console.

Comment: Is there any possibility to the WSO2IS version i use is not supporting this. My server version is "5.12.0-m12".

Comment: I figured out this. Problem was the username and password i have passed were wrong. thank you.

Comment: I am passing the right username and password but still getting empty {} in response, is there anything else that needs to be checked?
WSOIS version 5.11.0

Comment: My oidc-client config looks like this

```{
    authority: 'authority,
    client_id: 'client_id',
    silent_redirect_uri:`${window.location.origin}/callback`,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}/callback`,
    post_logout_redirect_uri:`${window.location.origin}/callback`,
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope:'openid profile',
    extraQueryParams:{
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 1800
}```